# Как передать один экземпляр абстрактного продукта?

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, абстрактная-фабрика

У меня есть абстрактная фабрика девайсов, которая производит телефоны и часы Apple и Samsung.
Часы Apple корректно работают только с одним результатом(телефоном Apple), но  принимают **любой** экземпляр телефонов в качестве аргумента. Как я могу передать только экземпляр телефона Apple и могу ли я это сделать через функцию `isinstance` ?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class DeviceFactory(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def create_phone(self) -> Phone:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create_watch(self) -> Watch:
        pass


class AppleFactory(DeviceFactory):

    def create_phone(self) -> Phone:
        return ApplePhone()

    def create_watch(self) -> Watch:
        return AppleWatch()


class SamsungFactory(DeviceFactory):

    def create_phone(self) -> Phone:
        return SamsungPhone()

    def create_watch(self) -> Watch:
        return SamsungWatch()


class Phone(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def GetNamePhone(self) -> str:
        pass


class ApplePhone(Phone):
    def GetNamePhone(self) -> str:
        return "Телефон Apple."


class SamsungPhone(Phone):
    def GetNamePhone(self) -> str:
        return "Телефон Samsung."


class Watch(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def GetNameWatch(self) -> None:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def connection(self, collaborator: Phone) -> None:
        pass


class AppleWatch(Watch):
    def GetNameWatch(self) -> str:
        return "Часы Apple."

    def connection(self, collaborator: Phone) -> str:
        result = collaborator.GetNamePhone()
        return f"Часы Apple можно подключить к {result}"


class SamsungWatch(Watch):
    def GetNameWatch(self) -> str:
        return "Часы Samsung."

    def connection(self, collaborator: Phone):
        result = collaborator.GetNamePhone()
        return f"Часы Samsung можно подключить к {result}"


def client_code(factory: DeviceFactory) -> None:
    product_a = factory.create_phone()
    product_b = factory.create_watch()

    print(f"{product_b.connection(product_a)}", end="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_code(AppleFactory())
    print("\n")
    client_code(SamsungFactory())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все зависит от того, чего вы хотите добиться. если вы хотите физически не дать возможность передать `ApplePhone` в `SamsungWatch.connection`, то можно сделать так:

```py
class SamsungWatch(Watch):
    def GetNameWatch(self) -> str:
        return "Часы Samsung."

    def connection(self, collaborator: Phone):
        if not isinstance(collaorator, SamsungPhone):
            raise SomeError
        result = collaborator.GetNamePhone()
        return f"Часы Samsung можно подключить к {result}"
```

в таком случае вы не сможете запустить код.

если же вы хотите сделать это неявным правилом, то можно, т.к это уже не абстракция, а конкретная реализация в `type hint` к принимаемому `collaborator` указать явно `SamsungPhone` вместо `Phone`. вы сохраните уровень абстракции, т.к `SamsungPhone` это надстройка над `Phone`, но линтер будет ругаться, если передадите не тот тип.

Comment: Могу я написать что-то вроде  `if isinstance(collaborator, SamsungPhone):` ... `else: return "Нельзя подключить" ` и получить в выводе "Нельзя подключить" ?

Comment: @VELIKS можете, вот только суть не изменится. так как вы не проводите каких либо действий, в том смысле, что в обоих случаях вы вернете строку. так как понять, можно ли подключить или нельзя?

Comment: по хорошему,  этот метод должен реализовывать какой либо функционал, в таком случае `return` какой либо строки может сигнализировать об ошибке. но я бы лучше просто рэйзил эту ошибку, а на уровне выше отлавливал бы

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй в AppleWatch

def connection(self, collaborator: Phone)

на

def connection(self, collaborator:ApplePhone )

Тебе же надо, чтобы AppleWatch при попытке подключить Samsung была ошибка?

Comment: вот только ошибку это не выдаст

Comment: А разве не должно быть ошибки типов? Если по прототип указан объект класса ApplePhone, а придёт объект класса Samsung Phone.

Comment: будет обычный ворнинг, в питоне нет строгой типизации