# Связанные объекты в абстрактной фабрике

Tags: ооп, архитектура, factory

Как задавать тип переменных в связанных классах при применении паттерна абстрактная фабрика?

Есть магазин телефонов Android и IOS, в магазине можно купить сам телефон и запросить сервисного инженера для его ремонта. Однако каждый инженер может чинить соответствующий тип телефона.

Должны ли методы repair_phone(self, phone: Phone) инженеров ожидать объект реализующий интерфейс Phone, если они нуждаются только в методах специфичных для своего телефона, или имеющих разные типы аргументов.

Вопрос схож с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331127/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0).

```
class Phone(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def turn_on_silent_mode(self):
        pass

    @abstactmethod
    def make_call(self, number):
        pass


class IPhone(Phone):

    # Abstract methods realization...
     
    # IPhone requires special password to unlock os
    def unlock_os(self, special_password):
        ...   

    def iphone_specific_operation(self, parameter: str):
        ...
        return 'Iphone specific operation done'


class AndroidPhone(Phone):

    # Abstract methods realization...
 
    # Android phone doesn't need password
    def unlock_os(self):
        ...   

    def android_specific_operation(self, other_parameter: int):
        ...
        return 'Android specific operation done'


class ServiceEngineer(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_repair_tax_value(self) -> int:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def repair_phone(self, phone: Phone):
        pass


class IPhoneServiceEngineer(ServiceEngineer):

    # Abstract methods realization...

    def repair_phone(self, phone: Phone):
        # IPhone engineer knows special password
        phone.unlock_os(special_password)
        phone.iphone_specific_operation(parameter)
        ...


class AndroidServiceEngineer(ServiceEngineer):

    # Abstract methods realization...

    def repair_phone(self, phone: Phone):
        # Android phone doesn't need password
        phone.unlock_os()
        phone.android_specific_operation(other_parameter)
        ...


class PhoneStore(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def buy_phone(self) -> Phone:

    @abstractmethod
    def create_service_engineer(self) -> ServiceEngineer:


class IPhoneStore(PhoneStore):

    def buy_phone(self) -> Phone:
        return IPhone()

    def create_service_engineer(self) -> ServiceEngineer:
        return IPhoneServiceEngineer()


class AndroidStore(PhoneStore):

    def buy_phone(self) -> Phone:
        return AndroidPhone()

    def create_service_engineer(self) -> ServiceEngineer:
        return AndroidServiceEngineer()


def main():

    phone_store = IPhoneStore()
    phone = phone_store.buy_phone()
    phone.make_call()
    service_engineer = phone_store.create_service_engineer()
    tax = service_engineer.get_repair_tax_value()
    service_engineer.repair_phone(phone)

    phone_store = AndroidStore()
    phone = phone_store.buy_phone()
    phone.make_call()
    service_engineer = phone_store.create_service_engineer()
    tax = service_engineer.get_repair_tax_value()
    service_engineer.repair_phone(phone)
```

Правильно ли выделить два дополнительных интерфейса (расширяющих интерфейс Phone), и указать их в методах repair инженеров?

```
class Phone(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def turn_on_silent_mode(self):
        pass

    @abstactmethod
    def make_call(self, number):
        pass
    

class IPhone(Phone):

     @abstractmethod
     def unlock_os(self, special_password):
        ...   
     
     @abstractmethod
     def iphone_specific_operation(self, parameter):
        ...

# Concrete IPhone
class IPhoneXR(Phone):

     # Abstract methods realization...


class AndroidPhone(Phone):

     @abstractmethod
     def unlock_os(self):
        ...

     @abstractmethod
     def android_specific_operation(self, other_parameter):
         ...

# Concrete Android phone
class Samsung(AndroidPhone):

     # Abstract methods realization...


class IPhoneServiceEngineer(ServiceEngineer):

    # Abstract methods realization...

    def repair_phone(self, phone: IPhone):
        ...


class AndroidServiceEngineer(ServiceEngineer):

    # Abstract methods realization...

    def repair_phone(self, phone: AndroidPhone):
        ...
```

Или стоит поискать другое архитектурное решение в данном случае?

Comment: По-моему, нет смысла создавать метод `ServiceEngineer.repair_phone`. Я не вижу сценария, когда вы у _какого-то_ `ServiceEngineer` вызовете `repair_phone` для _какого-то_ `phone`. Этого делать нельзя, сначала нужно будет убедиться, что этот конкретный инженер умеет чинить этот конкретный телефон. В месте, где будет эта диспечеризация, мы уже знаем типы и смысла их приводить к общим после этого не вижу.

Comment: "Этого делать нельзя, сначала нужно будет убедиться, что этот конкретный инженер умеет чинить этот конкретный телефон" Если мы используем конкретную фабрику, то она не гарантирует сочетаемость объектов? Можно рассмотреть пример по ссылке, с похожим вопросом (про телефон и часы) и предположить что метод connection() у разных часов, будет требовать специфичных методов у соответствующих телефонов.